# What does 'directed to standard output (cout)' means?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I just downloaded this code in which it says in the manual that the 'main results are directed to standard output (cout)'. However, when I run the code as described in the manual, everything runs just fine but I don't see any results showing on the terminal (not being written to an output file either)

This is a Linux code so I tried to run it form both Ubuntu terminal and from cygwin but I'm having the same problem - nothing is showing.

Could it be that 'the main results are directed to a standard output (cout)' means anything else? Other that it's supposed to show the results on the terminal?

Comment: Any chance of telling us which code you're talking about? Right now we don't know any more information than you do.

Comment: The code is an implementation of a method used in a paper. I had to request for the code from the Author so I don't think it's a good idea to share. I was just wondering if 'directed to standard output' might mean something else. Or if there's a configuration I should change in my terminal!

Comment: Not going to vote you down, but your question lacks detail. What program are you trying to run? From whence did you download it? Precisely what are the command-line arguments you are supplying? Give us instructions on how to reproduce your problem, and someone might be able to help you. SO is much better at answering concrete questions than these abstract hypotheticals.

Comment: When I'm faced with baffling code, there's two approaches I like to take: either (1) run the program with `strace(1)` and try to follow what it is doing (2) read the source code. Start at the beginning and follow the execution through mentally... Some people like to use debuggers (`gdb(1)` or its handy frontend `ddd(1)`) to combine the steps, but I find `strace(1)` often does well enough.

Comment: @sarnold Thank you. That's useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have the source code, it's a little difficult for you (or us) to tell if it may have another meaning ("directed to standard output (cout)" is a little hard to misinterpret however, there's no other sane reading of that snippet).

If you *do* have the source, you can look for the `cout <<`-type statements to ensure something is done. You may have to examine the logic closely to see why nothing is being output for your specific case.

If you can share the source with us, we could help out further but it doesn't appear you're comfortable with that so the "analyse the code yourself" is probably the best answer you'll get.

Of course, there's always the option of going back to the author if your analysis is not going well, or if you don't have the source.

Answer (score 3):

There's no other meaning that I can think of for "standard output (cout)" - it should be the terminal that's running the program. Are you sure the program produces output?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that there is no "wrapper" script encapsulating the program, which is internally redirecting the standard output to a file.